# Too many flags setting configurators/installers/authenticators 'webroot' -> 'nginx'

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've been been trying to install Certbot following the instructions on https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx However, when I try running `sudo certbot --nginx`, it returns `Too many flags setting configurators/installers/authenticators 'webroot' -> 'nginx'`

Who knows what to check in order to cope with this error?

Answer (score 8):

Check `/etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini` or `~/.config/letsencrypt/cli.ini` for any extra options you may have previously set.

In my case I had uncommented the `authenticator = webroot` line, so commenting this out again the command `sudo certbot --nginx` worked.